# Seek pagination to go to previous page

Tags: mongodb, pagination, seek

From what I understand, seek pagination concept is like this.
For example, i have these documents:

```
{ "_id" : "21cc6c1a-736b-4da8-bb5b-2b5d95533231", "timestamp" : "2021-02-16T03:17:55.163Z" }
{ "_id" : "f779e93e-80b8-43c7-866d-ce0a715d8d60", "timestamp" : "2013-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "8a8b17b3-10e3-4bd2-810d-4abf9f8558be", "timestamp" : "2012-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "7bf3bfc8-289a-4ae4-be50-1467832769be", "timestamp" : "2011-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "e4564e45-d7df-4cac-a91a-4f0796da38db", "timestamp" : "2000-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "be89c142-7e27-4ab8-bce1-488a3a6470fd", "timestamp" : "1999-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "f4156dfb-8d1e-4a46-991a-e381c73c929a", "timestamp" : "1998-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "ca6c6634-716d-448f-aebe-36c892da2719", "timestamp" : "1997-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
{ "_id" : "9b0062ab-4d9b-4e2b-b244-8e5a23c61b47", "timestamp" : "1997-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" }
```

To get the first 3 records, I query for per_page=3.

To get the next 3 records, I query for per_page=3, before_timestamp=2012-07-16T19:20:30.45Z, before_id=8a8b17b3-10e3-4bd2-810d-4abf9f8558be

To get the next 3 records (3rd page), I query for per_page=3, before_timestamp="1999-07-16T19:20:30.45Z", before_id=be89c142-7e27-4ab8-bce1-488a3a6470fd

How do I go to 2nd page from 3rd page?
Is this the only way?

```
per_page=3
before_timestamp=2012-07-16T19:20:30.45Z, (timestamp of last record in 1st page)
before_id=8a8b17b3-10e3-4bd2-810d-4abf9f8558be, (ID of last record in 1st page)
after_timestamp=1998-07-16T19:20:30.45Z, (timestamp of first record in 3rd page)
after_id=f4156dfb-8d1e-4a46-991a-e381c73c929a (ID of first record in 3rd page)
```

I wonder if theres a way to utilize after_timestamp and after_id only to go to previous page? Because although backend wise is OK, I'm not sure if it will be a good idea for the frontend to store timestamp and ID of last record of previous previous page.